# How to submit an rmd on kaggle?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kaggle

I've been searching for a answer but i couldn't find anything about.
I'm trying to submit my rmd on kaggle, but, when i do, i get this error message:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:6:
```

I think that the Rmarkdown script on kaggle is interpreting the text as a R code, which he shouldn't be doing.
I also tried do copy others people rmd and run it, and i keep getting the same message. You can try it yourserf with this markdown https://www.kaggle.com/dchudz/rmarkdown-starter-script to see what im talking about.

How to figure this out?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.kaggle.com/general/115570) helps.

Comment: I saw it and didn't helped :(

Comment: I haven't used .Rmd on kaggle yet, does kaggle render them for viewing or editing? what if you just save it as a .txt? let me know why a .txt would not work on Kaggle, I would like to learn more about .Rmd on kaggle